# After upgrading to gradle 3.0.0-alpha5 libraries are not resolved at compile time

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex, gradle-3.0

I recently upgraded to the new gradle 3.0.0-alpha5 after which some libraries are not resolved at compile time. However, all works fine at runtime, but when I try to include the missing libraries, I get runtime error.

this works at runtime but libraries are not resolved at compile time:

```
compile('jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.2') {
        exclude group: 'com.squareup.picasso'
}
```

this resolves the libraries but fails at runtime:

```
compile 'jp.wasabeef:picasso-transformations:2.1.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was having same problem recently. My workaround for the problem is as below.

First of all remove this library from the project and sync the project.

After successful sync you will get errors.

Now add this library again to the project and sync again.

Now your problem will be solved.